# Performance decrease when switching from 1.8.0_31 and earlier to 1.8.0_40 and later

Tags: java, performance, java-8, microbenchmark

For a littel concurrent framework I am writting, I created my own Thread scheduler, which lead to huge performance improve. For one specific Test 55ms instead of 87ms (with a ForkJoinPool) running time.
But I do see this improvment only in jdk 1.8.0_31 and earlier. In jdk 1.8.0_40 and later the Benchmark using my Scheduler needs 250ms, wheras the ForkJoinPool needs 230ms.
So the performance of both decrease, but my optimized version suddenly is slower then the unoptimized one.

Was theire any significat change introduced in 1.8.0_31 which could explain this performance decrease?

I read the JDK 8u40 Release Notes but couldn't find out what may cause this

**Additional Information:**

After some profiling (Sampling with visual VM) I think that the following line is alot slower on 1.8.0_40 then on 1.8.0_31

`public void exec(){
     res = fun.invokeWithArguments(args);
 }`

I found this out because on 1.8.0_31 the jvisualvm sampler indicates that 13.5% is spend in exec and 13.3% in generate (which is the function called by invokeWithArguments ). 
On 1.8.0_40 the jvisualvm sampler indicates that 33.2% spend in exec and 3.6% in generate.
This figures are for My Scheduler, but with the ForkJoinPool they show the same picture.

Has Something changed in 1.8.0_40 concerning MethodeHandles?

**Conclusion:**

I was able to elimitante the invokeWithArguments in the micro benchmark and replace it with a method call (sadly this is not possible outside of the benchmark, because the target methode will not be static).

Now the results are consistent independent of the java version: MyScheduler around 40ms, ForkJoinScheduler around 100ms

I still dont know why invokeWithArguments has such a huge performance decrease, still interested in an aswer if someone knows it.

Comment: Without a better look at your benchmark, I would say that 55ms = 87ms and 250ms = 230ms. There are a lot of factors that could play and explain the small difference, not related to your benchmark.

Comment: And also not related to the JDK versions. Can you still reproduce your first results going back to 1.8.0_31?

Comment: As @Tunaki said, details of your benchmark are needed. Especially, how many runs did you do to get your numbers? 55ms versus 87ms can be considered big, if it is the average of 1million runs, but if it is the timing of a single run, it is useless.

Comment: @Thiago Porciúncula: yes i can reproduce it with 1.8.0_31 and some other versions before that like 1.8.0_25, and I can reproduce the slow benchmark also with some never versions like 1.8.0_65.
I run the Benchmark several 100 times and thats the average over it, or to precise i run the benchmark until the average was stable (less then 0.0001% change between average over n-1 runs and n runs). 
I cant isolate the benchmark in something that fits here to stackoverflow because it does test my framework (which is more then some small classes).

Comment: Are you even sure the differences are related to threading? Maybe what you're doing *in the threads* is going slower?

Comment: @Durandal: Its the Same Programm, compiled and run with different jdk versions. If you meant the difference between My Scheduler and the Fork Join Scheduler, then they ultimatively run the exact same Tasks, but when they excecute which task and when they go to sleep, steal tasks etc... and how the exchange state between tasks, is different (that was the whole idea behind making a own scheduler, using domain knowledge to increase the performance)

Comment: Posted some additional Information, I will try as soon as I have time to get rid of the invokeWithArgument for the microbenchmark and if it solves the problem i will replace it with code generated over ASM at runtime.

Comment: Actually I meant the code executed as the actual workload; depending on which JRE classes are involved in the workload the cpu time may vary signficantly if the implementation of whatever you are using from the JRE changed. For example, I saw a huge drop in performance for a particularly evil Swing layout with many components, that worked ok in JRE6 but was unusably slow in JRE7.

Comment: @Durandal: yes that makes more sense and you were right, the code I added is in a thin layer which dispatches tasks to actual jvm functions, which from the view of the scheduler is already part of the workload. but the problem wasn't a external library function but the MethodHandles.